# Is it possible to generate a diagram of an entire Django webapp?

Tags: python, django, uml, diagram, program-structure

Is it possible to generate a diagram of an entire Django site? For example, to understand the model/database structure I use [graphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) which is extremely useful for keeping track of the model structure, and very useful for discussions.

I was curious if something similar existed for the complete Django site so that `urls/models/views/templates` could all be represented graphically. I don't quite know what that would look like but am curious if any tool exists to do this.

This would programmatically generate a diagram showing the code flow between different parts of the site.

Comment: I've started working on app that solves this. Its still quite barebones at the moment, but it [produces interactive HTML graphs from django model definitions](https://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs), like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/lvxSG.png

Comment: Nice! I'm checking it out now. Unfortunately this question is closed, otherwise I'd suggest adding it as an answer.

Comment: I've just released a solution for this too, with interactivity in the page: [`django-schema-graph`](https://github.com/meshy/django-schema-graph). [It looks like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meshy/django-schema-graph/9b034191776edc8c9608ef4e3f5414033f79d9a0/docs-images/schema-graph.png).

Answer (score 42):

You can use [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) app for generating model visualisations.

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    '...',

    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Give this command in terminal

```
python manage.py graph_models -a -o myapp_models.png
```

This will generate a png file named myapp_models.png. It will have visualised image of the models. More documentation can be found [here](http://pythonhosted.org/django-extensions/graph_models.html).

Comment: This is useful in general, but I am interested in advice on how to chose more than just the models.

Comment: The link above does not work anymore, use this one [graph-models](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html)

Comment: Not genarate .png, Error ends with: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_extensions', I have add 'django_extensions', in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 33):

[Here](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#python) you can find a list of Python-to-UML tools. The one called [GraphModels](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html) in [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) ([PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extensions)) may cover what you're looking for.

Comment: As far as I know, GraphModels is only for UML of models and not for the complete app.

Comment: Excuse me, [GraphModels](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html) can only successfully install on Linux? (couldn't install on Windows 10)

Answer (score 8):

I've stumbled upon this problem today and I found [django-dia](https://github.com/neumond/django-dia). It looks good, if you like Dia!

Comment: Error me: The term 'manage.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify th
at the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-extension for generating the app models i.e database. and also you can generate UML generating applications.